# How to make detected plane stable in Android using ARCore(Java)?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I'm working with ARCore and found that the detected `Plane` is not stable. **It is changing the position as well as orientation** on frequent `Frame`. So because of this, rendered 3D model or Textures are changing its position/orientation with the plane. How can I make `planes` more stable, or is there any alternative way to make objects stable?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest you don't have any possibility to change that behavior. Mapping depends on many factors like lightning or surrounding. Sometimes it drifts, sometimes it is very stable.